# Vuejs. E-Commerce & Shopping Cart

Tags: vue.js, e-commerce

how to save using Vuejs elements in the Shopping Cart when the user get in the website even if he refreshs the page later ?

Is **Vue-session** the perfect tool for that ?  Also, can you suggest me a good documentation for that ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions. One is handled on client side and other on server side. I would recommend to go with sever side which is solution 2, so that even when user opens the cart later, they can still see the items they added in cart. Amazon gas similar behavior.

**Solution 1**(client side): You can save the shopping cart details in localStorage or sessionStorage depends on your need and fetch the data from there when redirected to cart page

**Solution 2**(server side): This is done with the help of Backend in your project. Everytime you add a item in cart, you should send that information to BE(backend) and whenever you come to cart page, you should ask BE about the cart details

Comment: Thank you for your interest. how to work with solution 2 without auth ? How to get specifics details to the specific user without reconizing ?

Comment: You cannot work with solution with authentication. If Authenticaton is not required in your app(which is weird) as it is e-commerce app, then you should go with solution 1. But yeah, I know sometimes you want user to dk shopping and add items to cart and on checkout, you will ask for authentication. In that case, use solution 1 and save data in localstorage